# weird behaviour with .framework files and iCloudDrive

Tags: xcode, icloud-drive

I was wondering if anyone else has had this problem. I have my project files saved in iCloudDrive. As of late I have noticed that the framework files get duplicated and often aren't even the right size (i.e. Fabric, Crashlytics, FB). 
When I delete them, they reappear after a couple of days. The frameworks seem to be corrupt, Xcode won't compile them until I re-copy them from a non iCloudDrive source. Something about the header files not being found.

[image: Example of .framework-copies]

Does anyone have an idea what the cause of this is?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend to use `Git` instead of iCloud for versioning.

Comment: I am using git locally in that directory. I didn't make the multiple copies of the file - they were "created" by iCloud. Funny thing is I haven't opened this project for months.